# sum elements of an array by an indicies array into a smaller array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of N elements of type float called `a`. I also have an array of N elements called `b`. `b`'s elements are all unsigned integers in the range `[0, M-1]`. I want to get a float array of size M called `c`. `c` is just a "reduced" by summing up `a`'s element that falls into the same bin, defined in `b`.

Basically this operation:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2])
c = ?(a, b)
```

I want `c = [2, 5+7, 4+6+8+9, 0+1+3] = [2, 12, 27, 4]`

so, what is the name of this operation? and how can I do it in numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [numpy.bincount](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy-bincount).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2])

c = np.bincount(b,  weights=a)
print(c)

------------------

[ 2. 12. 27.  4.]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work (advanced indexing):

```
c = [a[b==i].sum() for i in np.unique(b)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder if there's a vectorized method to do this. or if such an operation has a name

Comment: This is pretty much as vectorized as can be I believe...

Comment: You can probably do something similar with `pandas.pivot` but I'm no pandas expert, and not sure it will ultimately be faster...